# How to write this better in Clojure

Tags: clojure

The structure of my hash is

```
(def *document-hash*   {"documentid" {:term-detail {"term1" tf1 ,"term2" tf2}})
```

I wan to find the tf. Right now I have this. Is there a better way to do this in clojure?

```
;; Find tf
(defn find-tf [documentid term-number]
  (if (nil? *document-hash* documentid)
       0
       (if (nil? (((*document-hash* documentid) :term-detail) term-number))
            0
            (((*document-hash* documentid) :term-detail) term-number))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated to work with a Ref:

```
(def *document-hash* (ref (hash-map)))

(dosync (alter *document-hash* conj {12603 {:term-detail {2 10}, :doclen 30}}))

(defn find-tf [documentid term-number]
  (or (get-in @*document-hash* [documentid :term-detail term-number])
      0))

(find-tf 12603 2) ; yields 10
```

Comment: It returns null even though I have a value.  Coud you try for this: (def *document-hash* (ref (hash-map)))

(dosync (alter  *document-hash*  conj {12603 {:term-detail {2 10}, :doclen 30}}))

Comment: If your document-hash is a ref, you'll have to replace *document-hash* by @*document-hash* (I'm editing my response to incorporate this).

Comment: `(or (get-in m [ks]) 0)` is just `(get-in m [ks] 0)`, unless he plans to store false/nil values in his map, in which case the latter handles them better anyway